# Fixed banner next to my wrapper?

Tags: html, css, css-position

So I am trying to make banners which scroll with the page, but always will be like 40px left from my wrapper.
This is my site: http://joostmeijer.eu/ so you can see how my html works.
I seriously don't get how I can make the banner div fixed but relative to my wrapper.

Comment: can you make a fiddle with some examples of what's not working for you? You want like publicity banners to always stay in the same place even if you scroll?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `<div>` inside your `wrapper` div, for example `<div id="fixedwrapper"></div>`, and then style it like this:

```
div#fixedwrapper {
     display: block;
     width: 140px;
     height: 500px;
     position: fixed;
     left: 0px;
     background: black;
}
```

Here's a live example: **[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7qa4bmmg/embedded/result/)**. Although you will need to use the CSS3 `@media-queries` to remove the banner when the window size is reduced since your website isn't responsive and the banner will overlap your content once the window size is reduced.

Comment: But the banner object still doesn't stick to the wrapper when resizing the page, and thats what I exactly want.

Answer (score 0):

You are contradicting yourself in the question. If a div has a fixed position it will position relative to the browser screen, so it will never ever move.

**Solution:**

If you do not want to change your html and keep the banner inside the div, you can apply a negative margin. Make sure the overflow on your wrapper is set on visible (default value) for this to work. Also make the image wider to fill up the gap you will create on the right by adding the pixels from the negative margin to your #banner div's width.

```
#banner{
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 540px; /*40px added to compensate for margin*/
  margin-left: -40px; /*move the dic 40 px to the left from the div*/
}
```

[Here it is in JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/5zsv0eo6/5/)

Is this what you are trying to do???